# using classes and objects creating a createID

Tags: java

I need some help with this project Im doing. It asks me to, "Prompt for and read the user's first name and last name (separately).  Then print a string composed of the first letter of the user's first name, followed by the first five characters of the user's last name. Assume that the last name is at least five letters long".
How would I correct the errors and have the desired output for test 1? Also, What am I doing wrong?[Test 1 Desired output[Test 2 desired output][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Wfu.jpg) Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMpZ0.jpg)

```
   class CreateID {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String id=("Clare");
  String Ids1, Ids2, Ids3;


  Ids1=id.concat(" Johnson");
  System.out.println(Ids1);
  Ids2=id.substring(0,6-10);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, get the first and last name of the user. You can use `java.util.Scanner` class to do it easily.

Assuming first and last names are stored in `String` variables `firstName` and `lastName`, use `firstName.substring(0, 1)` to get the first character in first name. To get first five characters of users last name, use `lastName.substring(0, 5)` The final result would be concatenation of these results, which can be obtained by using `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable class .So when you are using `String` methods every time new String object is returned.

> So instead of using id.substring(..) ,use IDs1.substring(..)then you wont get StringIndexOutOfBound Exception

Answer (score 0):

To explain the exception you're seeing, it's caused by this line:

`Ids2=id.substring(0,6-10);`

Which evaluates to

`Ids2=id.substring(0,-4);`

because it evaluates 6-10 as an arithmetic operation, which would be -4. Indices in java start at zero and increase, so they must be either 0 or a positive number. See the documentation for more information about [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).